# Webpack ExtractTextPlugin blues

Tags: sass, webpack, isomorphism

I cannot seem to get the ExtractTextPlugin working appropriately.  I've never seen a CSS file. Before I tried to switch to this plugin the scss files were being bundled without issue.

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: "dist/",
        filename: "bundle.min.js",
        publicPath: "/",
        sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.min.map'
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: ['babel'],
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css", "sass")
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.css")
    ],
    sassLoader: {
        includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, './stylesheets')]
    }
 };
```

SCSS file make the bundle.min.js file no problem with this...

```
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']
        }
```

But I need the CSS text to include in a server rendered response.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css", "sass")` you'll want to use `ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!sass")`. The API is a little weird that way.

Comment: I changed it to:

loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!sass")  - still didn't work

Comment: import '!style!css!sass!./stylesheets/APP.scss' - is how I am importing the file. This works when it is time to bundle.

Comment: I don't think you should need that at `import`. It will break the mechanism.